# How to get control the precision of contours in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to get equal value contour of a function. But I want the curve to be precise.

A naive way would be using `ContourPlot`, then extract the contour data. To do this, we need a utility to extract contours like below

```
ClearAll[extractContourAssoc];
extractContourAssoc[contourPlot_] := Module[{},
   tooltipData = 
    Cases[Normal@contourPlot, Tooltip[x__] -> {x}, Infinity];
   contourValueList = tooltipData[[;; , -1]];
   contourDataList = 
    Table[Cases[i, Line[pts__] -> pts, Infinity], {i, tooltipData}];
   AssociationThread[contourValueList -> contourDataList]];
```

Then for example

```
func[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
cplot = ContourPlot[func[x, y] == 1, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}];
```

to extract the contour in `cplot` , we use

```
pts = First@First@extractContourAssoc@cplot;
```

However, the precision is limited, for example, it we substitute back the coordinate of curves.

```
func @@ # - 1 & /@ pts
(*{-0.0025047, -0.00131712, -0.00137604, -0.00225737, -0.00143394, \
-0.00116087, -0.00113379, -0.00280045, -0.00107967, -0.00161928, \
-0.00143129, -0.000948526, -0.00279327, -0.00140771, -0.000650118, \
-0.000687417, -0.000736281, -0.000528992, -0.00106009, -0.000248064, \
-0.00138826, -0.00156147, -0.000895443, -0.00156147, -0.000757219, \
-0.00138826, -0.000248064, -0.00106009, -0.00126354, -0.000736281, \
-0.00190364, -0.00140771, -0.00034149, -0.000606891, -0.000948526, \
-0.00143129, -0.00161928, -0.00107967, -0.00280045, -0.000860253, \
-0.00113379, -0.00116087, -0.00143394, -0.00225737, -0.00137604, \
-0.00131712, -0.000643397}*)
```

If the curve is precise enough, then the numbers should all be zero.

Is there a way to get more precise contours? Though there is `MaxRecursion` option, but it seems that there is no precision control in `ContourPlot`.

---

**update**

Sorry I found I made a mistake about `extractContourAssoc`. `Line[pts__] -> pts` should be `Line[pts__] :> pts`

```
ClearAll[extractContourAssoc];
extractContourAssoc[contourPlot_] := Module[{},
   tooltipData = 
    Cases[Normal@contourPlot, Tooltip[x__] -> {x}, Infinity];
   contourValueList = tooltipData[[;; , -1]];
   contourDataList = 
    Table[Cases[i, Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity], {i, tooltipData}];
   AssociationThread[contourValueList -> contourDataList]];
```

And `MaxRecursion` actually works. For example, Set `MaxRecursion->10` will have precision roughly about `5x10^-6`. So the problem is solved.

Comment: you can take your contourplot results and use as initial points for `FindRoot`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) based approach instead? For instance:

```
eqn = x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1;
{xsol, ysol, diff} = Quiet @ NDSolveValue[
    {D[eqn, t], x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == 1, x[0]==1, y[0]==0},
    {x, y, x[t]^2+y[t]^2-1}, 
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}
];

ParametricPlot[{xsol[t], ysol[t]}, {t, 0, 2Pi}]
```

[image]

I included the difference you were interested in as an output of the [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) call:

```
Plot[diff, {t, 0, 2Pi}]
```

[image]

Finally, if you extract the Line object from the parametric plot, you will see that its errors are also less than $10^{-5}$ as well.

Comment: Hi, @Carl Woll. It seems that your method needs to know at least one precise point at first, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

A typical way is to polish with `FindRoot`.  Use the contour for one equation and the normal line for the second.

```
extractContourAssoc::noimpr = "No improvement possible in contour tagged ``";
extractContourAssoc[contourPlot_, {f_, x_, y_}] := 
  Module[{grad = D[f, {{x, y}}], contour},
   tooltipData = Cases[Normal@contourPlot, Tooltip[t__] :> {t}, Infinity];
   contourValueList = tooltipData[[;; , -1]];
   contourDataList = Table[
     Cases[
      i,
      Line[pts__] :> Block[{},
        (* check the Tooltip tag to see how to use it *)
        If[Head[i[[-1]]] === Equal,   (* tag is an equation with held variables *)
         contour = i[[-1]] /. Equal -> Subtract // ReleaseHold,
         If[NumericQ[i[[-1]]],        (* tag is numerical value *)
          contour = f - i[[-1]],
          Message[extractContourAssoc::noimpr, i[[-1]]];  
          contour = $Failed
          ]];
        (* improve the position if possible *)
        If[contour =!= $Failed,
         {x, y} /. 
            FindRoot[{contour, Cross[grad].({x, y} - #)}, Thread@{{x, y}, #}] & /@ pts,
         pts]
        ],
      Infinity],
     {i, tooltipData}];
   AssociationThread[contourValueList -> contourDataList]];
```

Example:

```
func[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
cplot = ContourPlot[func[x, y] == 1, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}];
```

The one-argument form of `extractContourAssoc` is the OP's function:

```
pts = First@First@extractContourAssoc@cplot;  (* OP's extractContourAssoc *)
func @@ # - 1 & /@ pts // RealExponent // Histogram
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The two-argument form is the one above that attempts to improve the position of the points with `FindRoot`:

```
pts = First@First@extractContourAssoc[cplot, {func[x, x], x, y}]; (* improved *)
func @@ # - 1 & /@ pts // RealExponent // Histogram[#, {1}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]